# How to control stripe transparency using ggforestplot/geom_stripes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was hoping to have some help in modifying the stripe transparency/shading color in the ggforestplot package. Please see the image below ("lighten" indicates the stripes I need to lighten). What is the best way of modifying the following code to do that?

Thank you so much for any pointers!

[image]

```
# Load and attach the packages
library(ggforestplot)
library (ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

#  Reproducible dataset
df <- ggforestplot::df_linear_associations %>% filter(  trait == "BMI", dplyr::row_number() <= 30)

# Draw a forestplot 
ggforestplot::forestplot(
  df = df,
  name = name,
  estimate = beta,
  se = se)+ 
geom_point(shape = 15, size = 5) +

geom_stripes( odd ="#00000000",  even = "#00000000") +

theme(legend.position="none",
     panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA))
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `ggforestplot::forestplot` already adds a `geom_stripes` layer with hard-coded default values for `odd` and `even`. Adding another `geom_stripes` will have no effect on this underlying stripes layer and will simply result in overplotting of the points, vertical lines, ... . To adjust the transparency you could (and TBMK need to) hack the internals:

```r
# Load and attach the packages
library(ggforestplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

#  Reproducible dataset
df <- ggforestplot::df_linear_associations %>% filter(  trait == "BMI", dplyr::row_number() <= 30)

# Draw a forestplot 
p <- ggforestplot::forestplot(
  df = df,
  name = name,
  estimate = beta,
  se = se) + 
  geom_point(shape = 15, size = 5) +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))

p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$odd <- "#00000000"

p
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that `forestplot` had an implicit `geom_stripes` call. That explains the observed behaviour. I have deleted my answer and removed the reference to my post in your answer. This is the correct answer. +1

Comment: @MauritsEvers. Haha. Actually it took me at least half an hour before I realized that this is the issue. And thanks to the comments in your answer I realized that the only option would be to hack the internals. Best S.